# GAE - Any performace benefits storing shorter names for datastore fields?

Tags: objectify, google-cloud-datastore

Do we get any performance benefits by naming the data-store fields with shorter names? As in while pulling the data from data-store we might get a benefit during data serialization and de-serialization?

Example: 
Before

```
@Entity
public class Data
{
    // Id
    private int id;

    // Name
    private String name;

    // Marks
    private long marks;
}
```

After:

```
@Entity
public class Data
{
    // Id
    private int id;

    // Name
    private String n;

    // Marks
    private long m;

}
```

Mainly when we fetch multiple[max 1000] records out?

Comment: I seriously doubt you would get any performance benefits from having shorter field names; and even if you did they would be very minimal at the expense of having readable code that is maintainable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical put operation takes about 50 to 100 msec, a get 10 to 20 msec and a query 20 to 100 msec. (You can check it with Appstat https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/appstats.) Most of this time is spend waiting for network or disk. What affects performance more is the number of properties that require indexing. The size of the whole entity is unimportant in the performance. Considering that the slowest instances run at 600Mhz, reducing few characters in the name of a field is negligible.